# Linking error OpenCV 2.4+CUDA windows 7(x64) command line

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, command-line, cuda, windows-7-x64

I am trying to compile a program that uses both CUDA and OpenCV.
I am sure that the paths to OpenCV are right because compiling a simple OpenCV program with this:

`cl /I"%OPENCV_DIR%\include" /LINK"%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_core240.lib" "%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_highgui240.lib" testCV.cpp`

it successfully compiles the program. Now when I try to compile with NVCC like this:

`nvcc testCuda.cu --cl-version 2010 --use-local-env -I"%OPENCV_DIR%\include" -L"%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_core240.lib" "%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc10\lib\opencv_highgui240.lib"`

I got an error when trying to link that says:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvLoadImage referenced in function main
a.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

What am I missing or doing wrong when compiling with NVCC?

Comment: Anyone any idea? I really don't know and cannot find why is this happening.

Comment: Any idea? Still looking for this to work !

Comment: Apparently, `cvLoadImage` is indeed located in `opencv_highgui240.lib` (at least it is in `libopencv_highgui.so` on Linux). Moreover, `-L` is used to specify library search paths (i.e. `"%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc10\lib"` in your case), while you need to use `-l` to specify libraries to be used in the linking stage (without the library file extension, e.g. `opencv_highgui240`). If you don't need CLI compilation, you could also follow the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831088/using-opencv-2-4-0-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project/10838338#10838338).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-L` is used to specify library **directories**, **not files**.

You probably want to execute:

```
nvcc testCuda.cu --cl-version 2010 --use-local-env -I"%OPENCV_DIR%\include" -L"%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc10\lib" -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_highgui240
```

If that doens't work, drop the `-l` and add their extensions:

```
nvcc testCuda.cu --cl-version 2010 --use-local-env -I"%OPENCV_DIR%\include" -L"%OPENCV_DIR%\x64\vc10\lib" opencv_core240.lib opencv_highgui240.lib
```

[Once upon a time](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-grayscale/downloads/list), when we had CUDA 2.x and OpenCV 2.1, I wrote a **Makefile** to compile an application that used both frameworks:

```
CXX=g++

CUDA_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
CFLAGS= -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include -I/usr/include/opencv 
LDFLAGS= -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib -lcudart -L/usr/lib -lcxcore -lcv -lhighgui -lcvaux -lml 

ifdef EMU
CUDAFLAGS+=-deviceemu
endif

all:
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp -o main.o -m32 -arch i386
    nvcc $(CUDAFLAGS) -c kernel_gpu.cu -o kernel_gpu.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) main.o kernel_gpu.o -o grayscale -arch i386

clean:
    rm -f *.o grayscale
```

Comment: Could you please tell, what is the purpose of `--cl-version 2010` and `--use-local`. I tried so hard, but still it gave me the error that `nvcc fatal   : Cannot find compiler 'cl.exe' in PATH`. So, I am using `-ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"`. It solved the problem related to finding path but now  it is giving me an error `nvcc fatal   : Option '--cl-version' needs to be specified with option '--use-local'`.

Answer (score 1):

May be a missing `-L` before the second library file like the first one?

Answer (score 1):

I was just able to link against cuBLAS on Windows by adding a pragma directive to my code:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"cublas.lib")
```

This might work with OpenCV as well.  Be aware that this is [non-portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685206/pragma-commentlib-xxx-lib-equivalent-under-linux), though.